# Task method to avoid hanging of form during process

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, task-parallel-library, invoke

I have process for large data and display of result to the textbox at the end of process.

Problem is that the form  becomes immovable for few seconds, it is not "not responding" hanging state or complete freezing, I'm able to stop process during execution with button. But I can't move form over the desktop for few seconds of processing.

I don't need to display result during process, it is displayed at the and of calculation with `Environment.NewLine` as complete list. But I want somehow avoid this short time fixed state of GUI

I tried to locate updating textbox display with UI operations into the task:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process(); 
    Display(); 
}

private void Display()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {              
        Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                /// Textbox output
            }));
    });
}
```

Now I can move form during the process, but if mouse click is pressed on the form, it just does not allows to display result until I release the mouse button. Also I'm not sure how safe this method is. I'm trying to figure out which Task method can be better and useful for this case.

Comment: Doing a StartNew to just do a Invoke does nothing for you, you just undid the benefit of being in a background thread. You need to do the work of processing before the Invoke then once you have results to display you can use the invoke to display it. (however you should look in to async/await using `Task.Run(` and awaiting is a lot easier solution)

Comment: You need the long running task to be run in a seperate thread that updates the UI via calling Invoke on the UI control. So a simple task like you have, that then calls another function periodically via Invoke to update the progress on the UI.

Comment: More generally, you should not use `StartNew` (use `Task.Run` instead) *and* you should not use `Invoke` (use `await` and/or `Progress<T>` instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invoke` method is being executed on UI context, tasks are being run in background. It doesn't make any sense to run operations in such way.

1. Make your event handler `async`
2. Do not use `StartNew` method, use `Task.Run` instead
3. `await` that task
4. Call `Display` method after that on UI context

So your code could look like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // run process in background
    await Task.Run(() => Process());
    // return to UI context
    Display(); 
}

private void Display()
{
    // Textbox output
}
```

Comment: For completeness I would sow the Process() method with a loop that calls a method that performs an invoke on the UI to update progress.

Comment: OP said that he doesn't need to show up the progress, only a result, so I didn't add that part

Comment: @VMAtm yes thank you, this way is very useful for this case

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Task` object like this:

```
Task myTask = new Task(new Action(()=>
{
// your operations code here
}));
myTask.ContinueWith(c=>
{
  yourControlName.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
 {
  // update control here
 }));
});
myTask.Start();
```

**note that you can also showdialog some sort of loading form while task is doing its job by creating it before the `Task`, disposing it in continue with blocks, and showdialoging it after task start**

Begininvoke will signal the thread that created the control to come and make changes to the ui, thing is

*if you dont specify the control name it will target the form here, and well they both share the same creator thread in your program but thats not the same in complex multi threaded applications*.

**Edit**
Thanks to VMAtm for pointing out that Task constructor is not recommended, i did a little digging and found this:
[msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/06/13/task-factory-startnew-vs-new-task-start/)

With that said
The right thing to do in your case would be :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( ()=>
{
  //computing here


      yourControlName.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
     {
      // update control here
     }));
}));
   // or display() here if you dont have to do it using begininvoke
```

***HOWEVER***
Since `StartNew` is dangerous according to [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) ( thanks to VMAtm again )
The best approach in your case would be:

```
await Task.Run(() => Process());
Display();
```

Note that all these work in your situation, its just a matter of which one is for which situation ideally...

Comment: This is not recommended way to create a task with `TPL`

Comment: @VMAtm tbh what is recommended depends on what the op wants to do, unless doing async and await , this must be the thing since backgroundworker has been discouraged by microsoft since the introduction of tpl. Beyond that is beyond the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: Task constructor is **not** recommended to use unless you're implementing a custom task scheduler.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i have updated my answer with documentation and i learned a new thing! 

Comment: Here is another blog :) http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @VMAtm thank you very much !

Comment: @Niklas Both solutions are useful for question above